# How to retrieve database column names in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table named "author" and when someone sign up and then visit his profile I want to show result like

```
Name : user name here
Email : email here
location : location here
```

Location, email and name are database column names. I can retireve the database value but I can not retieve the database column names. How can i do that?

Update:
Here is my code

```
$query = "SELECT * 
                      FROM author 
                      WHERE id = {$author_id};
 $author_info = mysql_query($query, $connection);
$author_details  =  mysql_fetch_assoc($author_info);
foreach ($author_details as $fieldname) {
echo $fieldname;
}
```

From this code i get only the value of name, location, email but i also need to print column names like name, email, location along with their column values.

Comment: Give the code you are using .

Comment: what do you mean by can not retieve the database column names? WHEN you execute `SELECT Name, Email, Location FROM Author` the header are called column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_field_name($index)`

Okay, let's suppose you already ran the query to get your data. this is how you can create a table with those data as you want. Or just use `mysql_field_name($index)` as you want. with this example you'll get the idea.

```
$numFields = mysql_num_fields($result); 

echo "<table id='whatever you want here'>";
        echo "<tr>";
            for($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++)
            {
                echo "<th>";
                    echo mysql_field_name($result,$i);
                echo "</th>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
                for($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++)
                {
                    echo "<td>$row[$i]</td>";
                }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: "mysql_field_name()" this is the function I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: you're welcome. I put it in the beginning of the answer for future reference by others.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query,

```
SHOW columns FROM your-table-name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a url like this:

```
www.site.com/profile.php?id=1
```

Your profile.php would look something like this:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT location, email, name FROM db WHERE id = " . $_GET['id']); 

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    echo $r['location'] . $r['name'] . $r['email'];
}
```

Just a guide line. You're open to sql injection and you should look into using PDO.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already know what you want these column names to be and you want them to be boilerplate text rather than dynamically selected from the database's metadata. In that case try concatenating boilerplate text onto your data and then giving the resulting column a column alias (for convenience in retrieving it in, for example, PHP code).

For example:

```
SELECT CONCAT("Name: ",name) AS name, CONCAT("Location :",location) AS location,
CONCAT("Email: ",email) FROM author WHERE id = 1;
```

However, this does seem a bit of an unusual thing to want the database to do -- as normally eg. if writing a PHP based application you would put the boilerplate text in your PHP page as HTML boilerplate text.

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach you need to use this form:

```
foreach ($author_details as $fieldname=>$fieldvalue) {...}
```

Without the `=>` in the foreach you only get the values, with it you get the key and value.

See the php [foreach documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)